# Can't access Fastly CDN sites through NAT

Tags: linux-networking, nat, cdn, wireguard

My office network nodes access internet via NAT (iptables masquerading) and the gateway server access internet using a Wireguard VPN connection.
Everything works OK, but I can't access websites that are using Fastly CDN.
Is there any additional configuration to avoid the problem?

There is a forward only DNS server on my gateway, that forwards all DNS request to my Wireguard server's DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question while looking into this issue myself.

I realize that you might have found the answer already but for others that might stumble upon this question -- here *is* the answer.

This is related to MTU/MSS issues.

Further discussion is available here :

- https://forum.level1techs.com/t/strange-issue-with-github-when-routing-traffic-over-wireguard-vpn/189403/10
- https://keremerkan.net/posts/wireguard-mtu-fixes/

TLDR, the fix is to set the MTU in your wireguard configuration to :

```
MTU = 1420
```

And also the following addition to your iptables FORWARD chain

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

Hope this helps someone!